# "Exception succesfully sent to server" event

Tags: c#, .net, exception, sentry

I'm trying to understand if there's a way to know if a notification is correctly sent to the Sentry cloud.
The reason is to show to the user the feedback.

I'm using this instruction:

```
SentryId id = SentrySdk.CaptureException(ex);
```

and I don't see any exception or notification fired if the notification is sent or not (eg: no internet connection) to the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it fails `id` will be equal to `Guid.Empty`. If it succeeded it will have a non-empty `Guid`. `SentryId` is a thin wrapper struct around `Guid` and has an implicit operator to `Guid`.

As for logging. Sentry has the concept of a [Diagnostic Logger](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/configuration/diagnostic-logger/) that should allow you to capture more detail on those failures

Comment: No, if you are offline the SentryId is a valid GUID. Is cached on the filesystem, but is not really sended to the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Simon's answer: That `Guid.Empty` vs `SentryId` part will tell you an event was queued for submission or not.
That means, if the SDK wasn't initialized, the event was dropped by your `BeforeSend` hook, or the queue was full, for example, you'd get back `Guid.Empty`.

If the SDK was correctly initialized and the event was queued for background submission, you'll get back that event's Id.

Now, it's possible the event is dropped at a later point, for example due to rate limiting, out of quota, etc. It's also possible the event was received by Sentry but then dropped due to an inbound filter configured on the server or the issue of which that event groups to was marked as "discard and ignore". So there's no one way in the SDK to know if for sure "the event should be in the dashboard" and if for some reason it's not, and you expect it to be, as @Simon suggested, it's best to start with the SDK diagnostic logging to check if the event is making its way through to the server in the first place.